# When is a function embedded in a {{}} called in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am extremely new to angular js but I was looking at code that had something like this

```
<div style="margin-top: {{increaseHeight()}}>
```

And that `increaseHeight()` function used a variable in the `$scope` variable for javascript something like the following

```
$scope.increaseHeight = function() {
    return $scope.value * 2;
}
```

What really surprised me was that every time `$scope.value` changed, the function `increaseHeight()` was called and the HTML was updated.  How is this done?  Does angular keep polling for changes to its scope and then call every single function that is defined in its `$scope` variable and then update the templates accordingly?

Sorry is this is a very obvious question.  I am really new to this and searching online did not really help much.  Thanks!

Comment: This is quite a complex topic regarding angular's digest cycle. A ~10 page description can be found at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the digest cycle is performed, your function is being called. https://www.thinkful.com/projects/understanding-the-digest-cycle-528/

This is an area where Angular could really use computed properties from VueJS.

In your specific case, you can do this for your style:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('TestController', function($scope){
  $scope.value = 5;
  $scope.style = {
    "margin-top": "5px"
  };
  $scope.$watch('value', function(newVal, oldVal){
    $scope.style = {
      "margin-top": (newVal * 2)+"px"
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController">
  <div class="box" ng-style="style"></div>
  <input type="number" ng-model="value">
</div>
```

Comment: Angular wouldn't have included $watch if it didn't have a purpose. To say that it should never ever be used ever is wrong. This is the exact case in which is should be used.

However, I didn't explain myself very well in my answer. I'm putting together an example to demonstrate it correctly.

Comment: I didn't say never ever be used. I said that it should be avoided, if you have other options rather than watch, there is no reason to use $watch... Second of all, he is not looking for other options to do it, he is asking what is happenning to his code and why is it happenning..

Comment: It's not as horrible as everybody you've been reading have been saying it is. It's just that many people don't know how to use it correctly. In this case, we're using it to simulate what VueJS calls "computed properties", which is what Angular ought to have, but doesn't. $watch makes it possible, and in this case is a perfectly fine solution to this problem.

Comment: @SamuelReid Are all member functions within the scope called when the digest cycle is run?

Comment: But he doesn't have a problem, he just wanna know what happens in a angular code and why it happens... Second, imagine his code growing and now he has 10 values with 1 $watch for each one, imagine the mess...

Comment: No, only the ones that are related to a property that is being updated. For example, you could make another function `$scope.foo = function(){console.log("hi!");}`, and that would not be called each time `$scope.value` is updated.

Comment: @SamuelReid How does angular know which function involves which variables? that seems like it would involve a "compiling" layer above regular javascript..

Comment: @Curious The answer is that angular doesn't. It simply updates everything.